# Build versioning for single application

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, versioning

Is it possible to keep many builds of single application on the iPhone device? For example if I want to have the history of builds:

```
Application 0.1 
Application 0.2
```

etc.

executables on device from single xCode project.
Currently if I change Product Name value from Targets info parameters to some different name it overwrite the binary with this new name on device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The device uses the bundle identifier to distinguish one app from another. If you give your builds different bundle IDs, they can be installed alongside each other.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your application does not need in app purchases or push notification which require a fully qualified bundle identifier, if you use a wild card bundle id com.yourapp.* you can change the bundle identifier for each application ie 
com.yourapp.0.1
com.yourapp.0.2

Its the differing bundle identifiers that allow you to install them along side each other

If you are making use of push or storekit, you would have to re setup this information on the Apple developer portal, which will probably prove time consuming. I would recommend in this instance you look at maintaining the applications on a webserver and use the OTA method to distribute the apps, then at least if you need a previous version it is easily accessible